# Валидация на пустые поля формы js

Tags: javascript

Есть форма, если одно из полей не заполнено нужно чтобы форма не отправлялась и рамка подсвечивалась красным и вылезала подсказка "Поле не может быть пустым".

```html
    <form action="post" class="form">
        <h3 class="form__titles">Контактные данные</h3>
        <div class="form__block">
            <div class="form__block-input-block form__name">
                <label for="name" class="form__label">ФИО<span class="span-red">*</span></label>
                <input type="text" id="name" class="form__name-input normal-input required-form-field" name="name">
            </div>
            <div class="form-input-error">Поле не может быть пустым</div>   
            <div class="form__block-input-block form__birth">
                <label for="birth" class="form__label">Дата рождения<span class="span-red">*</span></label>
                <input type="text" id="birth" class="form__birth-input required-form-field" name="name">
                <div class="form-wrap__tip-empty"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-input-error">Поле не может быть пустым</div>
            <div class="form__block-input-block form__phone">
                <label for="phone" class="form__label">Мобильный телефон<span class="span-red">*</span></label>
                <input type="text" id="phone" class="form__phone-input required-form-field" name="name">
            </div>  
            <div class="form-input-error">Поле не может быть пустым</div>           
            <div class="form__block-input-block form__email">
                <label for="email" class="form__label">Электронная почта</label>
                <input type="text" id="email" class="form__email-input" name="name">
            </div>
        </div>
        <button class="end-task-button button" type="button">Оформить заявку</button>
    </form>
```

```js
    function valid() {
    let form = document.getElementsByClassName('form');
    let fields = document.getElementsByClassName('required-form-field');


    form.addEventListener ('submit', function(){
        if(!fields[i].value){
            fields[i].style.border = '2px solid red'
        }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function isEmpty(val) {
  // Возвращаем булево значение
  return !!val;
}

const form = $('form');

$(form).on('submit', e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const inputs = $('input');
    $(inputs).each((index,input) => {
      const div_data = $(input).attr('id');
      const val = $(input).val();
      if(!isEmpty(val)) { // Если пусто — покажи ошибку
        $(`div[data-for="${div_data}"]`).fadeIn(300);
      } else {
        $(`div[data-for="${div_data}"]`).fadeOut(300);
      }
    });
});
```

```css
.form-input-error{
  display:none;
  color:red;
}
.span-red{
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="post" class="form">
  <h3 class="form__titles">Контактные данные</h3>
  <div class="form__block">
    <div class="form__block-input-block form__name">
      <label for="name" class="form__label">ФИО<span class="span-red">*</span></label>
      <input type="text" id="name" class="form__name-input normal-input required-form-field" name="name">
    </div>
    <div class="form-input-error" data-for="birth">Поле не может быть пустым</div>
    <div class="form__block-input-block form__birth">
      <label for="birth" class="form__label">Дата рождения<span class="span-red">*</span></label>
      <input type="text" id="birth" class="form__birth-input required-form-field" name="name">
      <div class="form-wrap__tip-empty"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-input-error" data-for="phone">Поле не может быть пустым</div>
    <div class="form__block-input-block form__phone">
      <label for="phone" class="form__label">Мобильный телефон<span class="span-red">*</span></label>
      <input type="text" id="phone" class="form__phone-input required-form-field" name="name">
    </div>
    <div class="form-input-error" data-for="email">Поле не может быть пустым</div>
    <div class="form__block-input-block form__email">
      <label for="email" class="form__label">Электронная почта</label>
      <input type="text" id="email" class="form__email-input" name="name">
    </div>
  </div>
  <input class="end-task-button button" type="submit" value="Оформить заявку">
</form>
```

Comment: Спасибо да труд)
Хочется ещё на чистом js понять как это делается.